# Opengl show vertex in 2d or 3d

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have question.
Is it possible to have two Vertex shaders. One will view vertex in 2D and second in 3D.
At the moment my program have 2D view. 
The only one difference between vertex in 2d and 3d will be that
vec2(x,y) in 3d will vec3(x,y,z). So i am thinking about sending to gpu vec3 and set gl_Position.z=0;

My biggest problem is that i choose magic numbers for glm:lookat and glm::perspective. If i see something it means that it works. So when i have 2d and 3d view everything looks bad.
I can move camera so doing 3d and changing position of camera only wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. But you can always render the same geometry multiple times, but with different glViewport and projection matrices applied. This is the canonical way to render the classical "top, front, side, perspective" views of 3D editors.

> My biggest problem is that i choose magic numbers for glm:lookat and glm::perspective.

Well, then I'd tackle that problem and instead of magical numbers use actual math to create the desired effect.

Comment: Hmm but i will have problem. Because if add hight(z). Even if i set view on front of map when i zoom i will see that this is not 2D.

Comment: @Luffy: You can always switch to a orthographic projection if you need one. You probably got your projection matrix setup places in a reshape handler. I suggest you move the calls to glViewport and the projection setup to the display handler. You can call them as many times you need. Use glViewport + glScissor to turn the window into multiple panes.

Comment: I dont have reshape handler but i will try to read about this. I am doing this in simple way i compute x, y draw them. I only use things from this tutorial http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/